# J2ME NullPointerException not getting caught

Tags: java-me

```
try{
        imgball = Image.createImage("/ball.jpg");
        //imgpad = Image.createImage("/ball.jpg");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}
```

The above code works as it is. But when i open imgpad statement, it gives me error of uncaught NullPointerException ? What can be wrong ?

P.S. I am working in a different Thread. If that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It was my mistake. I'd like to make it clear here for others to know.

The mistake I made was actually from the main thread. I'd written following :

```
        refcan = new ReflectCanvas(2); 
        d.setCurrent(refcan);
```

And I was loading images in the constructor ReflectCanvas(). So it could bear the speed upto one image but not for two :)

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException (NPE) must be later in your code. Your catch block will catch any NPE during image load.

Comment: It doesn't occur when I remove the second statement in the given block. And I dont make any change to rest of my code ..

Answer (score 0):

As mdma mentioned, the NullPointerException must be later because when the `Image.createImage("/ball.jpg");` fails, it will throw an Exception that you catch. Since you catch it and then do nothing, the value of `imgball` will be unset (`null`).

Since you are working from a different Thread, it's possible that you are accessing the variable too soon, but I assume the above reason is more accurate because `imgball` will probably always fail to be created since you give it the absolute path.